# None Standard Script Output OP_RETURN

Tags: op-return, non-standard-transaction

I'm trying to push 'hello world' in an op_return tx via blockchain.info and keep getting `None Standard Script Output OP_RETURN 68656c6c6f20776f726c64`.

Here's my script

```
6a0b68656c6c6f20776f726c64
```

It looks right to me. `6a` -> `op_return`, `0b` -> `11` which is the byte length, and `68656c6c6f20776f726c64` is `hello world`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my entire tx

```
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
```

Comment: The output is dust.

Comment: Does that mean I have to increase the value of my inputs?

Comment: @NickODell updated the value of my outputs so that op_return has a value of 1.5k satoshi and 10k miners fee. Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blockchain.info has buggy system which does not validate OP_RETURN outputs properly. Your transaction was pushed successfully using competent software.

[71c3da4e13f5b61c2cf05e9b5a22f3be989142b870c1cf7779a1d7b3f139d422](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/71c3da4e13f5b61c2cf05e9b5a22f3be989142b870c1cf7779a1d7b3f139d422)

Comment: ah. what did you use to push? I'll file a ticket with blockchain.info

Comment: I used `bitcoind`.

Comment: Try blockr.io/pushtx

Comment: hey @AakilFernandes, were you able to get anywhere with blockchain.info on this? Were you able to get any additional information from them?

Comment: @LeanMan sorry to say, but this was so long ago I don't remember

Comment: Its fine. I do appreciate you responding. I'm tracking down something and really appreciate you getting back to me.

Comment: hey @AakilFernandes, I know this was years ago but just curious do you recall the responsiveness of blockchain's ticketing service? It seems rather slow and also this thread said something similar: "They will take months to reply any question." https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3343715.0

Comment: you’re unlikely to get a meaningful response from them in any amount of time.